# Align 3 images vertically beside a larger image

Tags: html, css

So here's my code:

```
<div class="content_container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="slider" data-interval="1000">
            <img src="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <strong>Featured Items</strong>
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

The content_container parent needs to be responsive to the width, and I need the design to look like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this with CSS (aka not javascript)? I've tried messing about a bunch with flex boxes but it either doesn't line up vertically, or else it doesn't scale properly when the content_container parent is set to a specific width.

**EDIT:** The heights of the left and right need to match up no matter what images you load in.

Comment: Here is a quick example -> https://jsfiddle.net/mtp4mjLc/2/

Comment: @Morpheus That's something I tried, but when you load images in, the heights of the left and right side don't match up

Comment: Added some random images to show that the heights do match up -> https://jsfiddle.net/mtp4mjLc/3/

Comment: @Morpheus the heights of the divs match up, but not the heights of the images. Change the css to: `.left { width: 85%; } .right { width: 15%; }` to see what I'm looking for. But, the whole point of this question is I'm trying to do this dynamically instead of updating the width's manually.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}

.content_container {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right,
.right img {
   margin: 5px;
}

.left,
.right img {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 75%; 
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.right img {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="slider" data-interval="1000">
            <img src="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <strong>Featured Items</strong>
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```